# c++ logic, c# gui 

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, user-interface

I have to code a GUI with C# and the logic in C++. How do I create the project in Visual Studio 2010 so that there won't be any complications afterwards (when I will link both languages). Do I need Extensions/Plugins/whatever?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Create a C# project(s) and C++ project(s), you can do it in the same solution. It all depends of course whether your C++ application has to be .NET C++ (why not use C# instead?) or else you have to create a native C++ application. In that case, you are working with unmanaged code (and you have to be careful with that, using it in your C# project). BASICALLY: please provide us more context.

Comment: Why so negative? It's a legitimate design question. @Felix What kind of answer do you expect for 'What did you try'? The OP obviously wants to know about the first step, this is not about tracking down a bug in the code.

Comment: @Rotem Because this is not a question which belongs in on this site IMHO. It's not a problem he has actually faced, and before asking any questions ppl should try something out ( Like creating a solution and putting 2 projects in it ). If he faces problems after creating the solution he still can ask. I also do not ask if i can open the cold and hot water-pipes in my shower together, i go in and try it.

Comment: @Felix I understand what you're saying, but to continue your metaphor, I think what the OP is asking is equivalent to "If I open the cold and hot water-pipes in my shower together, will I have plumbing problems 6 months down the line?"

Comment: @Rotem I think it's not that what he is asking because he said: `How do I create the project in Visual Studio 2010 so that there won't be any complications afterwards (when I will link both languages).`, This is actually a Visual Studio related question.

Comment: @Felix Are VS questions not acceptable? (Retagged as Visual-studio-2010)

Comment: @Rotem You missed the point, VS-Questions are acceptable but not in the context `I never tried something, but how do i setup the project correctly`. If he asks `I have to develop a C++ and a C# project which work together, what are the best practices for this? Are there any plugins/ex.../.. which may help me to avoid problems with interop?`, THAT would be ok! But such a simple tasks he is asking about here ( creating the project ) is a task smb should try instead of asking here.

Comment: @Felix I agree completely with what you said, I just felt that your rephrasal of the question is exactly what the OP asked, or rather meant to ask. Let's put this debate to rest, we agree on the issue but not on the details.

Comment: @Rotem:  This is why so negative:  [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/142865)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you will need to have two projects, one for c# gui, one for c++ logic. As already mentioned, they can be put into the same solution. If you are ready to use managed C++ then your logic can be put into a class library which can be accessed by UI project in a traditional way. It's quite common to pack c++, even unmanaged, logic into a managed class interface.

Answer (score 1):

As logic in C++ managed code is already discussed. For calling the un-managed code in the managed code you can use [PlaPlatform Invocation Services (PInvoke)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). It `allows managed code to call unmanaged functions that are implemented in a DLL`. For example have a look on this MSDN code

```
// PInvokeTest.cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class PlatformInvokeTest
{
    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll")]
    public static extern int puts(string c);
    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll")]
    internal static extern int _flushall();

    public static void Main() 
    {
        puts("Test");
        _flushall();
    }
}
```